# Ruby on Rails - Primary and Foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I am creating a site in Ruby on Rails, I have two models a `User` model and a `Transaction` model.

These models both belong to an account so they both have a field called `account_id`

I am trying to setup a association between them like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I am using these associations like so:

```
user = User.find(1)
transactions = user.transactions
```

At the moment the application is trying to find the transactions with the `user_id`, here is the SQL it generates:

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'transactions.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE (`transactions`.user_id = 1)
```

This is incorrect as I would like the find the transactions via the `account_id`, I have tried setting the associations like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :transactions, :primary_key => :account_id, :class_name => "Transaction"
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :account_id, :class_name => "User"
end
```

This almost achieves what I am looking to do and generates the following SQL:

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'transactions.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE (`transactions`.user_id = 104)
```

The number `104` is the correct `account_id` but it is still trying to query the transaction table for a `user_id` field.  Could someone give me some advice on how I setup the associations to query the transaction table for the `account_id` instead of the `user_id` resulting in a SQL query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE (`transactions`.account_id = 104)
```

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :transactions
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, :through => :account
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001833

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the columnt `user_id` in the `transactions` table then you should use the `Account` model to select all transactions:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
  has_one :user # or has_many :users
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

User.find(1).account.transactions
```

Note that you have to remove `has_many :transactions` from `User` and `belongs_to :user` from `Transaction` as they assume that you do have the `user_id` column.

Answer (score -1):

I want to store data in address model that association with student model

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @address = Address.new      
    end

    def create
        @address = Address.create(:address_date => Time.now,
            :student_id => @student.id)
    end

    private

    def address_params
        params.require(:address).permit(:gali_no, :house_no_flate_no, :vill_town_city, :district, :state, :post_code, :country)
    end
end






class StudentsController < ApplicationController

    def show

    end

    def new
        @student = Student.new
    end

    def create
        @student = Student.new(student_params)

        if @student.save
            redirect_to root_url,  :notice => "You have been registered"
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    private
    def student_params
        params.require(:student).permit(:f_name, :l_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :mobile_no)
    end
end


class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :addressess, :dependent => :destroy

    attr_accessor :password

    before_save :encrypt_password

    validates_confirmation_of :password
    validates_presence_of :f_name
    validates_presence_of :l_name
    validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
    validates_presence_of :email
    validates_uniqueness_of :email

    def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
          self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
          self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
        end
    end
end




class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :student

end
```

Comment: You should construct the answer properly with proper syntax highlighting and indenting.